# Latest and greatest SqLite lib for .Net Portable Class (or at least Wp8.1 Unified)

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, mvvm, mvvmcross

If to run a Nuget search for "mvvmcross sqlite", there are 2 interesting top results:

1. Mvvmcross.Community.Plugin.Sqlite. Last published 09.02.14.
2. Mvvmcross.HotTuna.Plugin.Sqlite (old version, consider using Mvvmcross.Community.Plugin.Sqlite). Last published 17.01.15.

So, which one should i chose? The last updated version recommends to use version which was updated year ago.

EDIT: ah, there's also Sqlite.net Mvvmxcross extension, which is also seems to be quite promising.

Comment: This isn't a programming related question to a specific problem. Use any of the two versions which suits your needs!

Comment: Prototype all three, see which one feels better for you, go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up using Nosql Lex.Db for client. Too many problems with Sqlite in crossplatfom solution.